# How to determine if a user has set up an FB account in iPhone settings

Tags: ios, facebook, account

I would like to ask users if they would like to enable FB integration and provide a UISwitch for them to indicate their preference. However, I only want to have that option enabled/unhid in the event that the user has actually set up their FB account in the iPhones settings. How does one go about checking to see if they have even done that much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Here is the block of code that works for me. I welcome suggestions for improvement :)

```
self.myStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType *acct = [self.myStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];
    NSArray *fbAccounts = [self.myStore accountsWithAccountType:acct];

    // Check to make sure the user has a FB account setup, or bail:
    if ([fbAccounts count] == 0) {
        userDoesNotHaveFBAccountSetup = YES;
        self.fbSwitch.enabled = NO;
        [[self fbSwitch] setOn:NO];
        [self viewDidLoad];
    } else {
        userDoesNotHaveFBAccountSetup = NO;
        self.fbSwitch.enabled = YES;
    }
```

Comment: I found a problem with this approach. If the user has their FB details filled in the array returned will have a count of 1. If they do not, it will have an array of 0. But ONLY if they have accepted at least one dialog asking for permissions! Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

```
give it a try this will help you .....


        if(iOSVersion >= 6.0)
        {
                if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook])
             {
                     NSLog(@"user have filled fb acount details");
             }
             else
            {

                    NSLog(@"settings is empty");
            }   

        }
```

Comment: This is an interesting bit of code which I understand on the surface level but not why it would work. First, I must say that I attempted something similar to this originally, and it did not work for me.  Thinking about it, at the time it made sense to me that it would not work, because I would think that SLComposeViewController would be available for service type Facebook as long as you have the social framework installed!  Not just if you have filled in the FB details in your phones settings. Why SHOULD this work? Can anyone comment on that?